# Displaying search field with omines/datatables-bundle

Tags: doctrine-orm, datatables, symfony4

Im new to omines/datatables-bundle and I have problem displaying search.

I was studying [documentation](https://omines.github.io/datatables-bundle/) and was not able to get it working.
Ive created a table like this

```
$table = $dataTable->create()
          ->add('street', TextColumn::class, ["label" => "Street", "searchable" => true, "globalSearchable" => true])
          ->add('houseNumber', TextColumn::class, ["label" => "House number", "searchable" => true])
          ->add('postal', TextColumn::class, ["label" => "Postal Code", "searchable" => true])
          ->add('city', TextColumn::class, ["label" => "City", "searchable" => true])
          ->add('country', TextColumn::class, ["label" => "Country", "searchable" => true])
          ->createAdapter(ORMAdapter::class, [
            'entity' => CustomAddress::class,
          ])
          ->handleRequest($request);

        if ($table->isCallback()) {
            return $table->getResponse();
        }

        return $this->render('sales_request/add_custom_address.html.twig', ['datatable' => $table]);
```

Also, in my twig template

```
<div id="addresses">Loading...</div>
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/datatables/js/datatables.js') }}"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#addresses').initDataTables({{ datatable_settings(datatable) }}, { searching: true });
        });
    </script>
```

The datatable works fine, sorting is working etc, but I dont see the search input field.How should I configure it to display it?

Comment: Did one of the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone finding this issue by searching - it's actually a configuration issue we didn't document well enough.

The default Symfony recipe sets the [DataTables native `dom` option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) to a sane default, but it omits the search field as it's not universally required. In general one should configure the `dom` value correctly for the intended result.

For more information see https://github.com/omines/datatables-bundle/issues/57#issuecomment-453529328

Answer (score 1):

You can just add option dom : 'Bfrtip'

```
<div id="addresses">Loading...</div>
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/datatables/js/datatables.js') }}"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#addresses').initDataTables({{ datatable_settings(datatable) }}, { searching: true, dom: 'Bfrtip' });
    });
</script>
```